# List Element without iteration

Tags: python, list, find, iteration

I want to know how to find an element in list without iteration

Comment: your question is not clear. what exactly do you mean by "find element"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "without iteration"?  Are you actually talking about a dictionary (which uses hashes instead of iteration)?

Answer (score 9):

The [`mylist.index("blah")` method](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of a list will return the index of the first occurrence of the item "blah":

```
>>> ["item 1", "blah", "item 3"].index("blah")
1
>>> ["item 1", "item 2", "blah"].index("blah")
2
```

It will raise ValueError if it cannot be found:

```
>>> ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"].index("not found")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list
```

You can also use the `in` keyword to determine if an item is in a list (but not the location):

```
>>> "not found" in ["item 1", "blah", "item 3"]
False
>>> "item 3" in ["item 1", "blah", "item 3"]
True
```

As Harper Shelby commented, Python will still have to iterate internally to find the items, but the index or in methods may be *slightly* quicker than doing it in Python, as the data-structures are implemented in C.. but more importantly,

```
"x" in mylist
```

..is **much** tidier than..

```
found = False
for cur in mylist:
    if cur == "x":
        found = True
```

Comment: This is going to have to iterate under the covers - you can't search a list without iteration *somewhere*.

Answer (score 5):

This is a somewhat strange question. Do you want a hotline with `$someDeity`, or do you want another function to do the iteration for you, or do you want a *more efficient* way to test membership?

In the first case I cannot help you. In the second case, have a look at the [documentation on lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), specifically the `index` method. In the third case, create a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and use the `in` keyword. Note that set creation only pays off if you intend to search through the list many times.

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.index(2)
1
>>> 3 in l
True
>>> ls = set(l)
>>> 3 in ls
True
```

Comment: You don't need to use a set to use the `in` keyword.. >>> (3 in [1,2,3]) == True

Comment: @dbr: That's true, as my example already shows. set allows for a more efficient membership test, which is why I show both methods.

Comment: Converting the list to a set takes a lot of time. Using timeit.Timer, `3 in [1,2,3]` took 0.174s, `3 in set([1,2,3])` took 0.953s. With a larger list (1000 items) it took ever longer (9seconds for set, 1second for list). Moving the set([1,2,3]) code into to the timer setup code (so it's only run once) makes `x in set()` slightly quicker, about 0.01 seconds (total, when repeated 1million times!). I think converting to a set is probably more inefficient than just using the list, unless you need the other set() features..

Comment: Ah, of course if one wants to do only one lookup set creation does not pay off. It does in the case of a lot of lookups. (I should have noted this trivial fact, I guess. I'll update the answer.)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `in` syntax:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> 1 in l
True
```